# Angular - How to have multiple patchvalues for data retrieval

Tags: angular

In Angular-12 I have this:

API JSON Response:

```
"message": "Employee Detail.",
"error": false,
"code": 200,
"results": {
    "employee": {
        "id": 8,
        "first_name": "JONAH",
        "last_name": "YAKUBU",
        "other_name": "STANLEY",
        "licences": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "licence_number": "dsdsdsd",
        ],
    }
}
```

interface:

```
export class EmployeeResponse {
 results!: { employee: IEmployee;};
}

export interface IEmployee {
  id?: number;
  first_name: string;
  other_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  licence_number?: string;
}
```

component:

```
 profileInfoForm!: FormGroup;
 licenceInfoForm!: FormGroup;

 profileTemplate:boolean=true;
 licenceTemplate:boolean=false;

constructor(
 private fb: FormBuilder,
 private router: Router,
 private route: ActivatedRoute,
 private store: Store<AppState>
 ) {

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.isLoading = true;
  this._id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  this.updateEmployee();
  this.updateLicence();
  this.loadEmployeeById();
}

profileFunction(){
  this.profileTemplate=true;
  this.licenceTemplate=false;
}

licenceFunction(){
  this.profileTemplate=false;
  this.licenceTemplate=true;
}

updateEmployee(){
  this.profileInfoForm  = this.fb.group({
    id: [''],
    first_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    other_name: ['', [Validators.maxLength(50)]],
    last_name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  });
 }

  updateLicence(){
    this.licenceInfoForm  = this.fb.group({
    id: [''],
    licence_number: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2),
   });
  }

 get fp(){ return this.profileInfoForm.controls; };
 get fl(){ return this.licenceInfoForm.controls; };

 profileValidate() {
  if(!this.profileInfoForm.valid) {
    this.profileInfoForm.markAllAsTouched();
    return;
  }
 }

 licenceValidate() {
  if(!this.licenceInfoForm.valid) {
    this.licenceInfoForm.markAllAsTouched();
    return;
  }
 }

loadEmployeeById() {
 this.employeeService.getEmployeeById(this._id)
 .subscribe(
  (data: EmployeeResponse) => {
    this.employee = data.results.employee;
    this.profileInfoForm.patchValue({
      first_name: this.employee.first_name,
      other_name: this.employee.other_name,
      last_name: this.employee.last_name,
    });
    this.licenceInfoForm.patchValue({
      licence_number: this.employee.licence_number
    });
  }
 );
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="sticky-top mb-3">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title">Click to Edit</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div id="external-events">
          <button (click)="profileFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Profile</button>
          <button (click)="licenceFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-warning">Licence</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-header">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-9" *ngIf="employee != undefined">
  <div *ngIf="profileTemplate" class="card card-default color-palette-box">
    <div class="card-body">
      <form [formGroup]="profileInfoForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitProfile()">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="first_name">First Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control" required/>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="fp.first_name.touched && fp.first_name.invalid">
                  <div *ngIf="fp.first_name.hasError('required')">
                    <div class="text-danger">
                      First Name is required!
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="fp.first_name.hasError('minlength')">
                    <div class="text-danger">
                      First Name cannot be less than 2 characters!
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="fp.first_name.hasError('maxlength')">
                    <div class="text-danger">
                      First Name cannot be more than 50 characters!
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="other_name">Middle Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="other_name" placeholder="Middle Name" class="form-control" required/>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="fp.other_name.touched && fp.other_name.invalid">
                  <div *ngIf="fp.other_name.hasError('maxlength')">
                    <div class="text-danger">
                      Middle Name cannot be more than 50 characters!
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="last_name">Last Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control" required/>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="fp.last_name.touched && fp.last_name.invalid">
                  <div *ngIf="fp.last_name.hasError('required')">
                    <div class="text-danger">
                      Last Name is required!
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="fp.last_name.hasError('minlength')">
                    <div class="text-danger">
                      Last Name cannot be less than 2 characters!
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="fp.last_name.hasError('maxlength')">
                    <div class="text-danger">
                      Last Name cannot be more than 50 characters!
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="isLoading" class="btn btn-success" (click)="profileValidate()">
                    <span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                    <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="licenceTemplate" class="card card-default color-palette-box">
      <form [formGroup]="licenceInfoForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitLicence()">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="licence_number">Licence Number:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="licence_number" placeholder="Licence Number" class="form-control" required/>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="fl.licence_number.touched && fl.licence_number.invalid">
              <div *ngIf="fl.licence_number.hasError('required')">
                <div class="text-danger">
                  Licence Number is required!
                </div>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="fl.licence_number.hasError('minlength')">
                <div class="text-danger">
                  Licence Number cannot be less than 2 characters!
                </div>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="fl.licence_number.hasError('maxlength')">
                <div class="text-danger">
                  Licence Number cannot be more than 50 characters!
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="isLoading" class="btn btn-success" (click)="licenceValidate()">
                    <span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                    <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save</button>
          </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I have two tabs: Profile, Licence.

```
<button (click)="profileFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Profile</button>
```

Displays profile data to be editted

```
<button (click)="licenceFunction()" type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-warning">Licence</button>
```

Displays licence data to be editted

console.log(this.employee) displays all the data. But I observe that the patchValue is only displaying the data for profileInfoForm but licenceInfoForm.

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: your question unclear. are you saying "licenceInfoForm" is not working?
 "licence_number: this.employee.licence_number," also remove the trailing comma, that might be causing issue.

Comment: Maybe it is just because you spelled 'license' wrong (American / British spelling differs)? Console.log(data) to see how it is spelled coming from the back-end. If it is spelled right, could you make a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)? This way we can more easily help you and see more of the code.

Comment: If the `FormControl` names are same as the properties in the response object and the tabs _Profile_ & _License_ are defined in the same component and not lazy loaded, you could try patching the values in the `complete` handler of the `subscribe()` method after initializing `this.employee` object with the response object in the `next` handler of the `subscribe()` method.

Comment: @thisdotutkarsh - I have updated my code.  Form control names are not the same.    (click)="profileFunction() Displays profile data to be editted  while (click)="licenceFunction() should also display   licence data to be editted. But that of licence is blank. This has to do with loadEmployeeById

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 - I have updated my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue & Concern

`licence_number` doesn't exist in `employee` section according to your JSON. Instead, you need to get the first element of `licences` under `employee` section.

```
"employee": {
  ...,
 "licences": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "licence_number": "dsdsdsd",
    }
 ],
}
```

And your JSON is invalid. It should be as below:

```
{
  "message": "Employee Detail.",
  "error": false,
  "code": 200,
  "results": {
    "employee": {
      "id": 8,
      "first_name": "JONAH",
      "last_name": "YAKUBU",
      "other_name": "STANLEY",
      "licences": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "licence_number": "dsdsdsd"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Solution

You can use `map` RxJS operator to retrieve the first `licence_number` from `licence` array and transform the data.

> employee.service.ts

```js
getEmployeeById(id: number): Observable<EmployeeResponse> {
  return this.http.get('/assets/data.json').pipe(
    map((response: any) => {
      if (!response) return response;

      if (!response.results) return response;

      if (!response.results.employee) return response;

      let employee: IEmployee = {
        ...response.results.employee,
        licence_number:
          response.results.employee.licences &&
          response.results.employee.licences[0].licence_number
      };

      response.results.employee = employee;

      return response;
    })
  );
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4uvcwz)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because during invocation of `loadEmployeeById()` the `licenseInfoForm` template is not included in the DOM as the expression in the `ngIf` structural directive is evaluating to false.

You can perform the following in order to mitigate this,

- Store the value of the *license_number* returned by the response during invocation of `loadEmployeeById()` in an auxiliary object and patch its value to `licenseInfoForm` using `patchValue` upon the invocation of `licenseFunction()`